# SSRS: subreport from another server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreports

I'm creating new reports which should include several reports from different report servers as subreports. When doing this I'm referencing each report by a full path like `http://server1/ReportServer?/LegacyReports/Sales Report`

This gives an error:

> An error occured during local report processing.
>      An unexpected error occured in Report Processing.
>      An error occurred during local report processing.
>      Error in the application.
>      Illegal characters in path.

What is a correct way to reference reports from another server?

Comment: The illegal character is the `?`. Does your subreport's path actually have a ? in it?

Comment: You also need to specify the extension: `.rdl`.

Comment: Yes, without ? it doesn't give an error. But also doesn't work. This notation above is a shortest way I know to access a report from browser. This way works without mentioning .rdl.